# Building the vocabulary in document classification

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining

Assume I have a collection of documents and I want to use tf-idf as my document weighting measure. If I want my vocabulary to be of size 100, how do I choose those 100 words in the vocabulary? Considering training data as a whole and selecting the 100 top frequent words is not going to work here since my weighting system is tf-idf, right?

Answer (score 4):

A main use of tf-idf is to determine which terms might help you differentiate between your documents.  When a term is in every document its idf = log(1) = 0.  So the tf-idf for this term is always 0.  Likewise terms that are only in a few documents should be more useful for classifying and have the highest idf scores and tf-idf is also higher.

So the short answer is to just sort by tf-idf in descending order and take the top 100.  In my experience though you need between 5% and 20% of the terms.  Even if this doesn't always produce good enough results it's fast, simple, and I use it as my "baseline" model.  But quite often it's good enough for the domain I work in.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, once you've calculated the tf-idf values for all words in the whole collection of documents. You may use some **feature selection** methods to select the most pertinent features (words). Some common feature selection methods are **mutual information**, **information gain**, **chi-square**, etc. You can easily find their definitions on Wiki, and also, if you like, you may refer to this paper: ***Feature Selection for Text Classification Based on Gini Coefficient of Inequality***.